# Prove that $CE=AB$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Suppose $ABC$ is an acute-angled triangle with $AB<AC$.Let $M$ be the midpoint of $BC$. Suppose $P$ is a point on side $AB$ such that, if $PC$ intersects the median $AM$ at E, then $AP=PE$.Prove that $AB=CE$.

I don't know how to start. Please give me an idea. Getting no fruitful thoughts ,I started using barycentric Coordinates.But the calculations seemed very tough and I failed to proceed. Please give me any idea to start

Comment: I successfully bashed the problem with barycentric coordinates within 1 page!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:   write [Menelaus' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27s_theorem) for triangle $\,\triangle PBC\,$ and transversal $\,AM\,$.

Answer (score 2):

Construct the //gm BECF.

[image]

From (1) AEM is a straight line; (2) E is a vertex of that //gm; (3) M is the midpoint of one of its diagonals; and (4) F is a vertex of that //gm and FM is a straight line, we can say that AEMF is a straight line.

The required result follows because all the green marked angles are equal.

Comment: What does //gm mean?

Comment: @Angle I guess it stands for Parallelogram?

Comment: Nice solution +1

Comment: @Mythomorphic That is right.